# Accessing class constant trough property doesn't work

Tags: php, class, constants

Example:

```
class LOL{
  const
    FOO = 1;
}

$x = new LOL;
$arr = array('x' => $x);

echo $x::FOO; // works
echo $arr['x']::FOO; // works too
```

But if I make my class instance a property, I can't access the constant anymore:

```
class WWW{
  protected $lol;

  public function __construct($lol){
    $this->lol= $lol;    
  }

  public function doSMth(){
    echo $this->lol::FOO; // fail. parse error.. wtf
  }
}

$w = new WWW;
$w->doSMth();
```

:(

I know I can just do `echo LOL::FOO`, but what if the class name is unknown? From that position I only have access to that object/property, and I really don't want that WWW class to be "aware" of other classes and their names. It should just work with the given object

Comment: try this $w = new WWW(new LOL); ?

Comment: But if the class name is not known, how can you know it has `const FOO` to begin with? (unless all your classes are implementing some interface or extending some class)

Comment: because it expects that constant to be present :P

Comment: your WWW class isn't extending LOL. They're two completely different/separate objects

Answer (score 2):

You can do this much easier by assigning the `lol` property to a local variable, like so:

```
public function doSMth(){
    $lol = $this->lol;
    echo $lol::FOO;
}
```

This is still silly, but prevents having to use reflections.

Answer (score 1):

If the class name is not known, you can use [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/reflectionclass) to get the constant.  Note you must be using PHP 5 or greater.

Example:

```
$c = new ReflectionClass($this->lol);
echo $c->getConstant('FOO'); // 1
```

As of PHP 5.3.0, you can access the constant via a variable containing the class name:

```
$name = get_class($this->lol);
echo $name::FOO; // 1
```

For more info, see [Scope Resolution Operator - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Comment: This second piece of code doesn't work for me. It gets static, not constant. For static, I use this code:   $classvars=get_class_vars($Cl);
  $Res=$classvars[$Prop];
But what is the correct code for fetching a constant property, given the class and property names? There is no get_class_constants function.

Comment: (Only get 5 minutes to edit a comment here.) Only the kludge "eval("return $Cl::$Prop;")" works, and this won't work on a CSP-secure website due to the eval.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lol = &$this->lol;
echo $lol::FOO;
..
unset($lol);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Adding a brief explanation is customary when you add an answer.